# WordPress on AWS stack, core and plugins updates always fail

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've set up an AWS LAMP environment for WordPress. Everything is working except that WP core, theme, and plugin updates always fail silently. No error messages printed to the screen, nothing helpful printed to console, nothing tracked in error logs.

It's a basic AWS setup using EC2 behind a bastion server, S3, RDS, EFS and Cloudflare.

If I try to update plugins/themes in very small batches, like 1 at a time, the process sometimes works. Most of the time it just hangs for about a minute and then stops. Anything too big always fails.

Core updates always fail. It gets to "Unpacking the update…" and stops there. All in all it will try for maybe 60 seconds before the page simply stops loading despite max_execution_time being set to 300.

1) I've increased various php values that may help:
  `max_execution_time = 300`
  `memory_limit = 1G`
  `post_max_size = 25M`
  `max_input_vars = 1000`

2) I've checked, rechecked, and loosened permissions to webroot. Everything is good on this front. Everything owned by apache, which is the correct user. All directories 755. All files 644.

3) I've run the WP Health Check and everything comes up hunky dory. No problems reported here other than a nag to move from PHP 7.0 to 7.2.

4) I've done a fresh install of WP with clean DB and files, multiple times.

5) I've tried multiple versions of WP to rule out a 5.* issue.

I'm running 2019 theme with only basic plugins to rule out theme/plugin conflicts.

PHP error logging in enabled, WordPress debugging is enabled, but again, nothing writes to log or prints to screen.

I've done WordPress and LAMP for a long time so I'm leaning towards an AWS configuration here. I'm particularly suspicious of that bastion or something else preventing either outgoing or incoming communications.

Comment: Is your instance in a private subnet in a VPC, with an ALB in a public subnet to transit traffic from the internet to the instance?

Comment: Thank you @hephalump! I'm afraid I don't have the requisite amount of networking/AWS knowledge to answer your question as it's phrased. Are there some specific things I could lookup in AWS console to answer your question?

Comment: In EC2 do you have a load balancer?

Comment: Yes, there is a load balancer in EC2.

Comment: I’ve answered below. Hope it’s helpful; let me know if you need any clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application Load Balancers have a maximum timeout of 60 seconds. This means, they will only wait for, and return, a response from the target for up to 60 seconds before closing the connection.

When you do a batch update of plugins, or installing a large theme, the process of downloading, unpacking, and installing the plugins will almost certainly take more than 60 seconds.

We have faced this situation and although not ideal, one observation we have made with this scenario is that if we wait a few minutes and check the plugins, themes or core files, they will have actually updated. This is because although the ALB timed out, the Wordpress function is still executing and unless there is some other error, it will complete.

Comment: Your answer is tremendously helpful and makes a lot of sense. Good to know that I'm not the only one running across this. I'll be running the update via GUI tonight and will just let it run as you suggest. I'll report back here asap. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Good luck. As an aside, we tend to run updates via the WP CLI which avoids the issue all together.